# Cassandra - InvalidQueryException: Expected 8 or 0 byte long (10)

Tags: java, cassandra, bigint

I am getting below error when fetching records from Cassandra.

```
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.InvalidQueryException: Expected 8 or 0 byte long (10)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.InvalidQueryException.copy(InvalidQueryException.java:48)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.util.concurrent.CompletableFutures.getUninterruptibly(CompletableFutures.java:149)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestSyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestSyncProcessor.java:53)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestSyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestSyncProcessor.java:30)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:230)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.SyncCqlSession.execute(SyncCqlSession.java:54)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CqlTemplate.query(CqlTemplate.java:298)
    ... 58 common frames omitted
```

I have below table

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists dummy_table (
id bigint,
payload varchar,
bucket text,
create_date timestamp,
primary key (bucket, id))
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (id ASC) 
         AND COMPACTION = {'class': 'TimeWindowCompactionStrategy', 
                       'compaction_window_unit': 'DAYS', 
                       'compaction_window_size': 1};
```

and my Java entity looks like below and I am using java.sql.Timestamp for timestamp datatype.

```
@Table("dummy_table")
public class DummyTableEntity {

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "bucket", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private String bucket;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "id", ordinal = 1, type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED, ordering = Ordering.ASCENDING)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String payload;
    
    @Column("create_date")
    private Timestamp createDate;
```

My repository class is coded as below and method is called as findLimitedRecords('2021-01-01', 15L);

```
@Repository()
public interface DummyDao extends CassandraRepository<DummyTableEntity, MapId> {

    @Query("select * from dummy_table where bucket = ?0 and id <= ?0")
    public List<DummyTableEntity> findLimitedRecords(String bucket, Long id);
}
```

This code is run in spring boot and on calling 'findLimitedRecords' method. Code runs fine when I remove id.
May you please guide here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: should be `id <= ?1` instead of `id <= ?0` ?

Comment: Thanks @AlexOtt , it worked for me :)